# How to escape spaces while Set a parameter in Bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to do this:

```
@echo off
Set ^"Processes=Sample.exe ^
The Sample Program.exe^"
```

But `The Sample Program.exe` acting as three separate files `The` `Sample` and `Program.exe`.

What is the procedure to escape the spaces?

Full code:

```
for %%a in (%Processes%) Do (
    for /f %%b in ('tasklist /NH /FI "imagename eq %%a"') Do (
        if [%%b]==[%%a] (
            echo %%b is running
            Color 0C
            echo  Killing %%b ...
            Taskkill /f /im "%%b"
        ) else (
            Color 0A
            echo %%a is not running
        )
    )
)
pause & exit
```

Something along this line?
`for /F "tokens=1* delims=," %%b`

Comment: Inside a for loop you'd use `Sample.exe` and `"The Sample Program.exe"`, or preferably `"Sample.exe"` and `"The Sample Program.exe"`, so you appear to be missing the doublequotes, which are standrd to protect spaces in filenames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple demonstration code for what I think you want to achieve is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set Processes="cmd.exe Windows Command Processor" "cscript.exe Console Based Script Host"
for %%G in (%Processes%) do for /F "eol=| tokens=1*" %%H in (%%G) do (
    echo File name is: %%H
    echo Process name: %%I
)
endlocal
```

The output of this batch file on execution is:

```
File name is: cmd.exe
Process name: Windows Command Processor
File name is: cscript.exe
Process name: Console Based Script Host
```

So the environment variable `Processes` is defined with multiple strings enclosed in double quotes. Each string has first the file name of an executable without path and separated by a space (could be also a different character) the process name or whatever is needed to be associated with the executable file name which should not contain `?` or `*`.

The outer **FOR** loop assigns one after the other a string enclosed in double quotes to the specified loop variable `G`.

The inner **FOR** loop splits up the string assigned currently to loop variable `G` into two substrings and assigns the first normal space/horizontal tab delimited string to specified loop variable `H` and everything else after one or more spaces/tabs to next but one loop variable `I`.

The executable file name assigned to `H` and the associated string assigned to `I` can be used for whatever purpose in the command block of the inner **FOR** loop.

This method applied to what the batch file should do:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set Processes="notepad.exe Windows Notpad" "cscript.exe Console Based Script Host"
for %%G in (%Processes%) do for /F "eol=| tokens=1*" %%H in (%%G) do (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /NH /FI "imagename eq %%H" 2>nul | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I "%%H" >nul
    if not errorlevel 1 (
        echo %%I is running.
        color 0C
        echo Terminating %%I ...
        %SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /IM "%%H" >nul
    ) else (
        color 0A
        echo %%I is not running.
    )
)
color
endlocal
```

The option `/F` to force a brutal kill of the running process by the operating system is removed from this code. The most applications gracefully terminate itself on **TASKKILL** sending the **WM_CLOSE** message to the running application.

Please note that closing all instances of script interpreters like `cmd.exe`, `cscript.exe`, `wscript.exe`, `powershell.exe` as done by the **TASKKILL** with just image name passed as argument is in general not good. For example the `cmd.exe` instance currently processing the batch file would be terminated also on using this batch code to terminate a `cmd.exe` running with a different console window parallel.

Example for the unusual cases of executable file names with one or more spaces with using `|` as delimiter between file name and associated string which no file name can contain ever:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set Processes="notepad.exe|Windows Notpad" "cscript.exe|Console Based Script Host" "show time.exe|Show Time Information"
for %%G in (%Processes%) do for /F "eol=| tokens=1* delims=|" %%H in (%%G) do (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /NH /FI "imagename eq %%H" 2>nul | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I "%%H" >nul
    if not errorlevel 1 (
        echo %%I is running.
        color 0C
        echo Terminating %%I ...
        %SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /IM "%%H" >nul
    ) else (
        color 0A
        echo %%I is not running.
    )
)
color
endlocal
```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `find /?`
- `for /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `taskkill /?`
- `tasklist /?`

Answer (score 1):

Example based upon my comment:

```sh
Set ^"Processes="Sample.exe"^
 "The Sample Program.exe"^"
For %%G In (%Processes%) Do Echo %%G
Pause
```

Obviously when using `%%G` in your `/Fi`lter, you'd just remove those doublequotes, i.e. `%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /NH /Fi "ImageName Eq %%~G"`

*Please note that the leading space before any line which begins with a doublequote is required*